# generic method to update table on jdbc

Tags: java, sql, generics, jdbc

I've created a method to update tables on a database.

I've tried to do it on a generic way so it can be reused across different tables and with different conditions. Here is my code:

```
public void updateTable(String table, String column, String value, String[] conditions) throws SQLException
{
    PreparedStatement prepStatement = null;
    String query = "UPDATE ? SET ? = ? WHERE ";
    String[] condSplits;
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Integer i = 1;

    for(String parameter : conditions)
    {
        condSplits = parameter.split(" ");
        map.put(condSplits[0], condSplits[2]);
        query += "? "+condSplits[1]+"?";

        if(i == conditions.length)
        {
            query += " AND ";
        }
        i++;
    }

    prepStatement = this.con.prepareStatement(query);

    prepStatement.setString(1, table);
    prepStatement.setString(2, column);

    i=2;
    for(Map.Entry<String, String> condition: map.entrySet())
    {
        prepStatement.setString(++i, condition.getKey());
        prepStatement.setString(++i, condition.getKey());
    }

    prepStatement.executeQuery();
    this.con.commit();
}
```

I don't know if there's an easier way or better practices for this, what do you think?

I need to do it using JDBC instead of JPA.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It should be prepStatement.setString(++i, condition.getKey()); then prepStatement.setString(++i, condition.getValue());

Comment: conditions should not be an array of String to parse but an array of a POJO

Comment: if(i == conditions.length) should be if(i < conditions.length)

Comment: yeah a few typos, sorry about that :-/ thank you!

Comment: I'm afraid you will hardly get an answer as it is "primarily opinion-based", indeed there are millions ways to do it and this is one way